# Loading properties

Tags: java, angularjs-factory

So i have a file called app.properties which contains to urls in the format of
somethingurl=http://.../.../.../something.js

Note:there is actual url

But i switched to an internet less environment and cannot get the files.
So instead, i replaced the urls with actual paths to the files that i downloaded.
But i get a java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol. So now i have the files that urls were pointing and i try to use them create an instance of JSFactory.

So is there a way to make the paths work?

I use to jsoup.connect(app.properties.getProperty("...")).ignoreContentTyp(true).execute().body();

Can i still use file: protocol?

Comment: Can you show us the file + code?

Comment: And why not use the [`file:` protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) to have a valid URL?

Comment: "Can i still use file: protocol?" why don't you try?

Answer (score 1):

Use `file` protocol. `file:///path/to/your/file.js`